# How to add our social posts to in my umbraco website?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I want to display anytime we post on twitter, facebook, etc... they'll show up as content (image and post) on my Umbraco site.
I found Umbraco package **uShare** but it is not capable of Umbraco 7.7
any other way please suggest me.

Comment: are you saying you want have created a `DocumentType` for social posts, and want to dynamically create objects based on some web-service?, or you just want to embed twitter/facebook code in some side-bar widget?

Comment: I want to create DocumentType for the number of the post like I enter 5 then latest 5 posts show up as content (image and post) on my Umbraco site.

Comment: So you basically want to have the content of the social media post copied to Umbraco nodes? That doesn't sound like a good idea to me. What if change the content of the post? Should the changes automatically be applied to umbraco? This way an action in Umbraco should be triggered once a new post is added or you'll have a polling mechanism to poll for changes or new messages. An easier way in my opionion would be to directly connect with the twitter/facebook api and get the social media posts using a client side script